# PWM signal gets disrupted when writing to a file (TMS320F28379D)

Tags: embedded, debugging, dsp, texas-instruments

I am trying to establish a form of communication between my DSP (TMS320F28379D launchpad) and a .py script on my laptop. I have a .csv file with 7 duty cycle values from 0.2 to 0.8. My objective is to output a PWM signal corresponding to a given duty cycle value and when the user enters an input value of '1' into a dedicated variable in CCstudio, the DSP should save '1' to the .txt file which when read by the python script enables saving the oscilloscope screen to another file. After saving successfully, the .py code should erase and save '0' to the same .txt file. This will be read by the DSP and then when it reads '0', it will move to the next duty cycle value and a corresponding PWM signal is generated.

My issue: Saving the data and PWM signal generation works fine. The problem is while scanning or printing '0' or '1' by the DSP. Whenever, it enters a while loop containing fgetc or fputc, the PWM signal is disrupted for a second or so. It seems as if the CPU has halted. But, once this reading or writing operation is complete, everything goes back to normal. I tried increasing the heap and stack size within the linker file for the DSP but the issue persists. Removing this issue is important because I wish to interface this DSP with a gate driver circuit. Here is the C-code for the DSP:

```
#include "F28x_Project.h"
#include "F2837xD_device.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include "device.h"

#define BufferSize 256

extern void Init_SysClk(void);
extern void Disable_Watchdog(void);
extern void Init_Buffer_ADCResult(void);
extern void Config_ADC(void);

extern void Config_GPIO(void);
extern void Init_EPWM1(void);
extern void Init_EPwm1GPIO(void);
extern void Config_EPWMADC(void);
extern void Read_D_and_freq(void);       // The function to read the .csv file to get D and f values.
extern void continue_flag(void);
extern void Init_read_txt(void);


extern Uint16 ADCA_Data[BufferSize];     // Buffer for results
extern Uint16 index;                     // Index into result buffer
extern volatile Uint16 buffer_Full;      // Flag to indicate buffer is full

extern long int f_BCLK;                  // The final PLL clock frequency which is 100 MHz.
extern float duty[];                     // The duty cycle of the PWM signal.
extern double T_BPRD[];                  // T_BPRD = f_BCLK/(2*f_PWM) (in counts).
extern long int freq[];                  // Frequency of the generated PWM signal.
extern int conf[];                       // The confirm signal array within the .csv file.
extern double comp[];                    // The comparator value to generate the PWM signal (comp = duty*T_BPRD).
unsigned int to_save = 1;                // Used to call the read_txt_isr1 interrupt in main().
extern int end_here;                     // The number of useful rows in the .csv file.
extern char data_from_csv[100];
extern char *sp;


// Declarations related to the .txt file that is used to communicate with the .py script...
FILE *txt_file;                        // The .txt file.
FILE *csv_file;
char txt_filepath[100] = "C:\\Users\\J\\Desktop\\Work_related\\SIG.txt"; // Path
char csv_filepath[100] = "C:\\Users\\J\\Desktop\\Work_related\\sig_data.csv";
int loop_count = 0;                             // Can be used for iterations.
long int temp = 0;//discard after use! (just a dummy var).
int c = 1;
int temp2 = 0;
char csv_data[100];
char *csv_entry_onebyone;
char *one_to_txtfile = "1";
int j = 0;
int skip_line = 0;
int user_input = 0;

Uint16 a;
Uint16 ReadData;

__interrupt void epwm1_isr1(void);
__interrupt void adca1_isr1(void);
__interrupt void sciarx_isr1(void);
__interrupt void read_txt_isr1(void);     // Creating an interrupt to read the .txt file to get confirmation signal from the .py script.

char circ = '0';

void main(void)
{

    DINT;

    Disable_Watchdog();
    Init_SysClk();
    Config_GPIO();
    Init_EPwm1GPIO();

    Read_D_and_freq();                    // Function to read the D and freq values from the .csv file (Intentionally kept before the PWM and ADC functions).
    Init_EPWM1();                         // Set the duty cycle for the EPWM1A generation here.
    Init_read_txt();
    Config_EPWMADC();

    Init_Buffer_ADCResult();
    Config_ADC();

    EALLOW;
    PieCtrlRegs.PIECTRL.bit.ENPIE = 1;    // Enable vector fetching from ePIE block

    //PieCtrlRegs.PIEIER1.bit.INTx1 = 1;    // Enabling ADCA1 at PIE level
    //PieCtrlRegs.PIEIER3.bit.INTx1 = 1;    // Enabling EMPWM1 at PIE level
    //PieCtrlRegs.PIEIER9.bit.INTx1 = 1;    // Enabling SCIA_RX at PIE level
    //PieCtrlRegs.PIEIER3.bit.INTx12 = 1;    // Using EPWM12 interrupt to read the .txt file.

    //PieVectTable.ADCA1_INT = &adca1_isr1;            // Mapping ADC1 ISR to PIE Vector Table.
    //PieVectTable.EPWM1_INT = &epwm1_isr1;            // Mapping EPWM1 ISR to PIE Vector Table.
    //PieVectTable.SCIA_RX_INT = &sciarx_isr1;         // Mapping SCIARX1 ISR to PIE Vector Table.
    //PieVectTable.EPWM12_INT = &read_txt_isr1;        // Mapping Read_txt_ISR to PIE Vector Table.
    EDIS;

    IER = 0xFFFF;                                    // Enabling group3 interrupts at CPU level

    EINT;                                 // Enable global interrupt

    loop_count = 0;
    txt_file = fopen(txt_filepath, "w"); // Tells the python script to save the data from the scope.
    fprintf(txt_file, "%d", 1);
    fclose(txt_file);
    while(loop_count < end_here)
    {
        GpioDataRegs.GPASET.bit.GPIO18 = 1;

        EPwm1Regs.TBPRD = (int)T_BPRD[loop_count];             // Determines the frequency.
        EPwm1Regs.CMPA.bit.CMPA = (int)comp[loop_count];       // Duty ratio = 0.5

        for(temp=0; temp<10000000; temp++);                     // A small delay.

        if(user_input == 1)  // "user_input" = 1 tells whether to save the data.
        {
            // Wait until the save process is complete...
            while(1)
            {
                txt_file = txt_file = fopen(txt_filepath, "r"); // Tells the python script to save the data from the scope.
                if(txt_file == NULL)
                {
                    fclose(txt_file);
                    break;
                }

            }
            for(temp=0; temp<10000000; temp++);                     // A small delay.
            loop_count++;
            user_input = 0; // Resetting the user input to 0 upon save completion.

            txt_file = fopen(txt_filepath, "w"); // Tells the python script to save the data from the scope.
            fprintf(txt_file, "%d", 1);
            fclose(txt_file);
        }

        GpioDataRegs.GPACLEAR.bit.GPIO18 = 1;
    }
}
```

I tried everything mentioned on TI's forum, but nothing solves the issue. I am using .txt files to communicate here as I just need '0' or '1' to be sent between the two devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCS uses *C I/O* to perform `stdio.h` functions. As per [Stop-mode C I/O](https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/sdto_cgt_tips_for_using_printf.html#stop-mode-c-i-o) this involves the target stopping on a breakpoint which disrupts the target operation.

Some possible alternatives are:

1. Using [Real-time Mode](https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/users_guide_12.4.0/ccs_debug-main.html#real-time-mode) which can allow interrupts to still be serviced while the processor is halted at a breakpoint.
2. Use [C2000 GUI Composer](https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/training/modules/gui_composer/c2000-guicomposer-xds.html) to communicate with the target. [Target Communication](https://dev.ti.com/gc/v2/help/GC_UserGuide_v2/targetprog.html#target-communication) has some more information on the possible communication mechanisms. Changing to use GUI composer will require a change to the target code.

Admittedly I haven't tried the above myself.

Comment: Although I have declared interrupts there, I haven't mapped them. This code was from an earlier project and I updated it to perform this function. I will try what you have said and will let you know. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I checked real-time mode, but it didn't work.  I will check out the GUI composer and let you know.

Comment: It seems that I have to use some other means of communication instead of reading and writing to text files. I will use UART as an alternative. It is also simpler, I think.